# pandas where method results in a different outputs when using the inplace kwarg

Tags: python, pandas, in-place

I am getting different results when using the `where` method with  `inplace=False` vs `inplace=True`.

my question is why would this happen (am i doing something wrong?) and are there any more methods that behave in a similarly unexpected way.

consider the following `dataframe`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,None,3]})
df
    a
0   1.0
1   Nan
2   3.0
```

when using the `where` method with `inplace=False` (the default), i get the following result:

```
df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
    a
0   1.0
1   None
2   3.0
```

with `a` being converted to be of type `object`.

however if i do this:

```
df.where(pd.notnull(df), None, inplace=True)
df
    a
0   1.0
1   Nan
2   3.0
```

`a` is of type `float64`

pandas version: 0.23.3 , numpy version: 1.14.5

Comment: Same problem in `pandas 0.23.1`, I think it is bug. You can report it in [pandas github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: reported the [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22051)